# How to prevent function from passing values to slot

Tags: functions

For the following example:

```
{#, #} & /@ {1, 2}
```

I am trying to find a method to hold one of the slots (or both ) so that the function do not pass the values to the slot I want to protect. for example I want to get something like this:

```
{{1, #}, {2, #}}
```

I tried all type of Hold on the second slot but without and success.

any suggestion?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Maybe something like (using [`Inactive`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Inactive.html)):

```
Activate[{#, Inactive[Slot][1]}] & /@ {1, 2}
(* {{1, #1}, {2, #1}} *)
```

Comment: IMO `Activate` should be internal to the function.  I assumed this as a requirement; if not other options such as simple replacement open up.  I am editing your answer accordingly; if you disapprove simply revert the edit.

Answer (score 16):

It depends on what you want to do with result, but you could try like this:

```
Function[{x}, {x, #}] /@ {1, 2}
```

> {{1, #1}, {2, #1}}

Answer (score 13):

Using `Function` with a named parameter, as halmir showed, is the standard way to do this, however anything that prevents a literal `Slot[1]` from appearing in the body of the `Function` will work.  `Inactive` as chuy showed is one possibility, but I find this cleaner:

```
{#, Slot @@ {1}} & /@ {1, 2}
```

> ```
> {{1, #1}, {2, #1}}
> ```

If the body will not be evaluated you can use `With` instead:

```
With[{$ = Slot}, Hold[#, $@1] ] & /@ {1, 2}
```

> ```
> {Hold[1, #1], Hold[2, #1]}
> ```

Answer (score 7):

You can also use `Block` for this:

```
Block[{slot = #}, {#, slot} & /@ {1, 2}]
```

> {{1, #1}, {2, #1}}

This works because `Block` implements dynamic scoping, so the symbol `slot` is not replaced by `#1` until `slot` is evaluated (i.e. *after* the `Function` has been created and mapped over the list). As pointed out by Mr. Wizard, this means that if `slot` is never evaluated the replacement will not occur. For example:

```
Block[{slot = #}, Hold[#, slot] & /@ {1, 2}]
```

> {Hold[1, slot], Hold[2, slot]}

Comment: Not generally you cannot: `Block[{slot = #}, Hold[#, slot] & /@ {1, 2}]`.  This is why I showed `With`.  And for the case where the body does evaluate I still prefer `Slot @@ {1}`.

Comment: The good thing about this method is if you want to use the result one following operation you don't need to Evaluate first.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard if one goes to extremes, the `With` solution will also rename lexical stuff inside. `With[{$ = Slot}, Hold[#, Module[{y}, $@1]]] & /@ {1, 2}`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, good point, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I stand by @MrWizard's answer. The natural way is with named functions. If it is evaluated, an alternative is anything that prevents `Slot[1]` from appearing literally. Personally I like `Identity[Slot][1]` more than `Slot@@{1}`. 
If you insist on "protecting" a slot, the only way I know is with another function, so this would work.

```
{#, First[# &]} & /@ {1, 2}
```