# Dynamic updating of Slot number

Tags: manipulate, function-construction, dynamic

I want to change the slot number inside `Manipulate[]`. Here is a minimal example which does not work:

```
Manipulate[Sin[#n] & [0, Pi/2], {n, Range[2]}]
```

I expect an output of 0 when `n=1` and 1 when `n=2` (sine evaluated at n-th argument).

I've also tried `Slot[n]`, `# n` but they do not work either. I couldn't find any similar question.

How would you make it?

**EDIT 1**

Kuba's answer

```
Manipulate[Evaluate@Sin[Slot[n]] &[0, Pi/2], {{n, 1}, Range[2]}]
```

works for the minimal example. In my case i use it while plotting graphics:

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{min, max, col},
  {min, max} = Through@{Min, Max}@pointslf[1][[All, n]];
  col = {"TemperatureMap", {min, max}};
  Graphics3D[{ColorData[col][#6], PointSize[Large], 
      Point[{#1, #2, #3}]} & @@@ pointslf[1]]
  ],
 {n, Range[6, 7]}
 ]
```

If i substitute #6 with `Evaluate@Slot[n]` it doesn't work anymore. `pointslf[1]` is a matrix with coordinates (first three columns) and other stuff (next columns) i use to define the color.

How should i do it in this case?

Comment: Try `Manipulate[
 Sin[# n] & /@ {0, Pi/2},
 {n, Range[2]}
 ]`

Comment: @Nasser that gives Slot multiplied by n  not the nth slot.

Comment: @GordonCoale I thought that is what op wanted. May be I did not read the question carefully.

Comment: Why not simply `Manipulate[
 sel = {0, Pi/2};
 Sin[sel[[n]]],
 {n, Range[2]}
 ]`

Comment: @Nasser I suspect the op wants a version that works with slot even though its not necessary in this simplified example.

Comment: Related: [(56412)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/56412/121)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
Manipulate[Evaluate@Sin[Slot[n]] &[0, Pi/2], {{n, 1}, Range[2]}]
```

but I don't think it is as handy as:

```
Manipulate[Sin[{0, Pi/2}[[n]]], {{n, 1}, Range[2]}]
```

Comment: But the evaluate version will be much neater and more readable if you are passing in named slots from a dataset, then you can pass a popupmenu string or similar straight into your code.

Comment: @GordonCoale Probably you are right, it depends of the case. Just keep in mind that Evaluate works only on first level of held expression so for more complex cases you may have to do less readable incjection. P.s. Here Function (...&) is what forces us to use Evaluate.

Comment: @Kuba Your code works for the minimal example, but in my case it does not work. I've edited my post with the real use.

Comment: @mnunos Try `Graphics[Evaluate[...]& @@@ ...`.

Comment: @Kuba Thanks, that works! Could you explain me why do i have to use Evaluate like that? Before asking i also tried `Slot[Evaluate[n]]`, it didn't work and i dont understand at what level do I have to use it.

Comment: @mnunos I already explained, in my first comment.

Comment: Kuba, I think this could be closed as a duplicate of [(46751)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/46751/121).  Please tell me if you agree or disagree.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I agree

Answer (score 2):

A simple workaround is to use [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html) and [`SlotSequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SlotSequence.html) like this:

```
ColorData[col][{##}[[n]]]
```

Another workaround is to generate the function that is applied (`@@@`) with another function:

```
pointslf[1] = RandomReal[1, {12, 7}];

Manipulate[DynamicModule[{min, max, col, fn},
  {min, max} = Through@{Min, Max}@pointslf[1][[All, n]];
  col = {"TemperatureMap", {min, max}};
  fn[n_] := {ColorData[col][Slot[n]], PointSize[Large], Point[{#1, #2, #3}]} &;
  Graphics3D[fn[n] @@@ pointslf[1]]],
  {n, Range[6, 7]}
]
```

This is essentally the same as Kuba's method, merely presented in a different style.
Yet another way to write the same thing:

```
Graphics3D[With[{n = n}, {ColorData[col][Slot[n]], PointSize[Large], 
     Point[{#1, #2, #3}]} &] @@@ pointslf[1]]
```

The specific method is not important but rather the evaluation that it achieves.  The body of a [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html) is not evaluated due to `Function` having the [`HoldAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldAll.html) attribute.  We need to inject the value of `n` into this body to achieve what you want.  In this particular case you can evaluate the entire function body with `Evaluate`, but in other cases you would *not* want to do that as unwanted evaluation would occur.

Regarding `Evaluate` see [Explicit use of Evaluate not behaving the way I expect it to](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/47907/explicit-use-of-evaluate-not-behaving-the-way-i-expect-it-to/47947#47947)