# Create an indexed list of functions

Tags: list-manipulation

I am trying to use a Table to create the following object:

```
{f[#,1]&,f[#,2],f[#,3]}
```

The obvious doesn't work,

```
Table[f[#, j] &, {j, 1, 3}]
```

It gives:

```
{f[#1, j] &, f[#1, j] &, f[#1, j] &}
```

leaving the j unevaluated. I assume that's due to the HoldAll attribute of Function. How do I get around this? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Also see: [(56412)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/56412/121)

Answer (score 3):

Some possibilities:

```
Table[With[{j = j}, f[#, j] &], {j, 3}]
Function[{j}, f[#, j] &] /@ Range[3]
f[#, j] & /. List /@ Thread[j -> Range[3]]
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work.

```
Table[(f[#, i] &) /. i -> j, {j, 1, 3}]
(* {f[#1, 1] &, f[#1, 2] &, f[#1, 3] &} *)
```

Note that `#1` and `#` are equivalent.