# How to use Select according to a list of criteria to produce a list of subsets of another list obeying those criteria

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching, pure-function

The code

```
Print[Select[{1, 4, 3, 9}, Mod[#, 3] == 0 &]];
Print[Select[{1, 4, 3, 9}, Mod[#, 3] == 1 &]];
Print[Select[{1, 4, 3, 9}, Mod[#, 3] == 2 &]]
```

gives `{3,9}`, `{1,4}` and `{}`, as expected.
But the code

```
Map[Select[{1, 4, 3, 9}, Mod[#, 3] == ## &] &, {0, 1, 2}]
```

gives `{{1}, {1}, {1}}`, rather than `{{3, 9}, {1, 4}, {}}`, which is what I want.

What I am doing wrong? Is there a better way to achieve the same result than by using `Select`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your attempt is that both `#` and `##` in your expression are interpreted as both being arguments to the pure function that you're feeding as the second argument to `Select`. To nest `Function`s like this, you have to take one of them and use the non-short-hand version:

```
Map[Select[{1, 4, 3, 9}, Function[{x}, Mod[x, 3] == #]] &, {0, 1, 2}]
```

More cleanly, I would just use `Table`:

```
Table[Select[{1, 4, 3, 9}, Mod[#, 3] == k &], {k, {0, 1, 2}}]
```

But really, in this case, I think it's better to use `Cases` or `Pick`, because you can select the elements using `Pattern`s rather than truth-value `Function`s, reserving the pure function for the `Map`ping over `{0, 1, 2}`:

```
Cases[{1, 4, 3, 9}, a_ /; Mod[a, 3] == #] & /@ {0, 1, 2}
Pick[{1, 4, 3, 9}, Mod[{1, 4, 3, 9}, 3], #] & /@ {0, 1, 2}
```

---

To elaborate on why the version in the OP doesn't work, we can note that their code is essentially equivalent to

```
Map[Select[{1, 4, 3, 9}, Function[{x}, Mod[x, 3] == x]] &, {0, 1, 2}]
```

In other words, in each case, the elements of `{0, 1, 2}` are irrelevant, and the function is just checking if `Mod[x, 3] == x` is `True` for each of `{1, 4, 3, 9}`, and `1` is the only one that works.

Answer (score 2):

```
Outer[If[Mod[#2, 3] == #1, #2, ## &[]] &, {0, 1, 2}, {1, 4, 3, 9}]
(* {{3, 9}, {1, 4}, {}} *)
```

or more "sophisticated"

```
Pick@@Transpose[ Outer[{#2, #1 == Mod[#2, 3]} &, {0,1,2}, {1,4,3,9}], {2,3,1}]

(* {{3, 9}, {1, 4}, {}} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to use `Association` and `GroupBy` (under Mathematica v10), **so that each element is tested only once**. If you can accept a different structure for the output:

```
GroupBy[{1, 4, 3, 9}, Mod[#, 3] &]
```

> <|1 -> {1, 4}, 0 -> {3, 9}|>

But also preserving your structure is not difficult:

```
Lookup[GroupBy[{1, 4, 3, 9}, Mod[#, 3] &], Range[0, 3-1], {}]
```

> {{3, 9}, {1, 4}, {}}

---

You can also use this [trick](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/56412/how-to-prevent-function-from-passing-values-to-slot)

```
Select[{1, 4, 3, 9}, Function @@ {#}] & /@ (Mod[Slot @@ {1}, 3] == # & /@ {0, 1, 2})
```

> {{3, 9}, {1, 4}, {}}

---

If you need often this construct, you can also define your own helper's *crit* as in

```
equalToMod[m_][n_][k_] := Mod[k, m] == n
Select[{1, 4, 3, 9}, #] & /@ equalToMod[3] /@ {0, 1, 2}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using map and select causes all elements of {1, 4, 3, 9} to be tested 3 times rather than 1:

```
n = 3;
SortBy[GatherBy[Join[{1, 4, 3, 9}, Range[0, n - 1]],
         Mod[#, n] &], Mod[First[#], n] &][[All, ;; -2]]
```

Edit: This is probably better:

```
n = 3; L = {1, 4, 3, 9};
Lookup[Map[L[[#]] &, PositionIndex[Mod[L, n]]], Range[0, n - 1], {}]
```

Comment: That is fantastic, Coolwater ! My first attempt had a Do loop, which tested the elements of the big list 3 times instead of once. My first attempts at improving the code were aimed at exactly this problem.

Comment: Your edit with `Lookup` and `PositionIndex` returns `{{3, 4}, {1, 2}, {}}`...